# How to data compare the price or, subtotal in Ubercart flat rate shipping quotes

Tags: 7, ubercart

Using Drupal 7.43 and [Ubercart](https://drupal.org/project/ubercart) 7.3.9
I am trying to set up flat rate shipping for two parameters.

1. For orders with a subtotal above $34.00
2. For orders with a subtotal below $34.00

Unfortunately, there are no options under data comparison for the Subtotal... Only the Order total.

Or, I would like to create a flat rate shipping rates that vary by price ranges.

1. For products with a price above $34.00
2. For products with a price below $34.00

Can't figure that one out either. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... I had negate checked!
This is how I did it...

Data comparison
Parameter: Data to compare: [order:delivery-address..., Data value: United States

AND

Data comparison
Parameter: Data to compare: [order:order-total], Operator: is greater than, Data value: 34

---

Data comparison
Parameter: Data to compare: [order:delivery-address..., Data value: United States

AND

Data comparison
Parameter: Data to compare: [order:order-total], Operator: is less than, Data value: 34